# catching all invalid URLs

Tags: php, url, redirect, url-rewriting

I recently upgraded a site and almost all URLs have changed. I have redirected all of them (or so I hope) but it may be possible that some of them have slipped by me. Is there a way to somehow catch all invalid URLs and send the user to a certain page and somehow know what URL the person came from so I could log this, and fix those? I'm thinking I could use .htaccess somehow but am not sure how. I am using PHP Thanks so much!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use a custom [`ErrorDocument`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/core.html#errordocument) handler written in PHP to catch URLs having "slipped by":

```
# .htaccess file
ErrorDocument 404 /not-found.php
```

And in `not-found.php`:

```
switch($_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL']) {
    case '/really_old_page.php':
        header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
        header('Location: /new-url/...');
    /*  As suggested in the comment, exit here.
        Additional output might not be handled well and
        provokes undefined behavior. */
        exit;
    default:
        header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
        die('404 - Not Found');
}
```

Comment: great, this is what I was looking for. I imagine I could catch other errors besides 404 this way with .htaccess? thanks.

Comment: If I am using a custom 404 page like you mentioned and i happen to land on the default: switch case, I want to display an error page (something like google.com/sdfsdfsdf/ but as I understand the first thing on the page I must do is header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found'); and then die() right after so no content would be displayed after that. How can i display the error page + header() + die() ? Thanks!

Comment: @Kentor `die` is really just an alias for `exit`. Simply put your error page's content *after* the 404 header. You cannot, however, redirect to another page, if you're concerned about properly sending an HTTP 404 code. The redirect would overwrite that code w/ either 301 or 302.

Comment: just in case anyone is interested, I would like to add that you should always exit(); or die(); after header("Location: /url/"); otherwise php will still execute anything that comes after the redirect. @goreSplatter you may want to add that in your answer if you want..

Answer (score 2):

in .htaccess in the web root

```
ErrorDocument 404 /yourFile.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest would be to add a custom 404 redirect in htaccess.

Just add something like this:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404.php
```

to a .htaccess (create one if needed) in your application root. And all request to none extistent pages will be redircted to your own custom 404 page.